# NPP_New not getting called in few webpages (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, safari-extension, browser-plugin

I am trying to access NPAPI plugin from content/inject script of Chrome/Safari extensions.

The code to embed the plugin object and access methods.

```
var newElement = document.createElement("embed");  
newElement.id = "myPluginID";  
newElement.type = "application/x-mychrome-plugin";
var newAttr = document.createAttribute("hidden");
newAttr.nodeValue = "true"
newElement.setAttributeNode(newAttr);
newElement.style.zIndex = "-1";
newElement.style.position = "absolute"; 
newElement.style.top = "0px";
document.documentElement.appendChild(newElement);
plugin = document.getElementById("myPluginID"); //this shows as HTML element when evaluated in JavaScript console.


   plugin.myPluginMethod() // this shows as undefined instead of native code(When evaluated in JavaScript console),for pages where NPP_New is not called.
```

This works for most of the webpages,but for few pages(eg:www.stumbleupon.com),NPP_New is not called(debugging using Xcode 4) and scriptable object is  not created and all the plugin methods are undefined.

Any inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you putting your embed as a child of `document.documentElement` (i.e., `<html>`) instead of in the body? I wouldn't expect a plugin that's not going to be displayed to be instantiated.

Comment: In addition, put it into the body before you set the type.

Comment: Thanks smorgan... removing the code for hiding the embed element fixed the issue.